# CSS radio-button label selector

Tags: css, radio-button

I'm trying to modify my radio button using the following criterion:

- "No" radiobutton turn red and display 'N' as content when clicked or hovered over
- "Yes" radiobutton turn green and display "Y" as content when clicked or hovered over

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/putoz/2/edit

The problem is that I can't find the correct CSS selectors for ".yes-label" and ".no-label" lasses.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bageduru/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the id attribute to distinguish between buttons?

Something like this to change background color on click:

```
input[id="appointment-yes"]:checked + label:before { ;}  
input[id="appoinment-no"]:checked + label:before { ;} (appointment-no is missing a 't'?)
```

And then change background color during hover with these?

```
.yes-label:hover:before { ; }  
.no-label:hover:before { ; }
```